# Get the full Instagram source code content of a person I'm following with private account in python

Tags: python, html, instagram

I am using this python code to get a specific part of an Instagram source code of the user "xpto":

```
import urllib.request
import re

pat = re.compile('<script type="text/javascript"> ***what I need here*** </script>')

url = "http://www.instagram.com/xpto/"

sock = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")

li = pat.findall(sock)
```

The thing is: I want to have access to the full source code of the account "xpto" (which I am following), like when I login in Instagram through a browser, search for "xpto" and right click on the option "view source code".

But if I simply use this code, the program doesn't know I follow "xpto" so it doesn't give-me the full HTTP content of his page (like the description of the last pictures posted, for example) as it does in a browser like I explained before, or with an user that doesn't have his account private.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram

Comment: what are you trying to do with the source code? most likely, there's an API you can use to get the data you want